# EC2 won't connect to internet

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apt-get

I have a freshly setup EC2 instance on AWS, however it seems it won't connect to the internet... I have searched far a wide and everything I come across doesn't change anything. Here are the errors I'm getting, let me know if more info is needed.

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                               
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.26), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31), connection timed out
Err:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                          
  Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.201.250.36), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.229.132.181), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.229.150.131), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.237.137.22), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.73.36.184), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.91.65.63), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.207.133.243), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.152.129.43), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.165.17.230), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.172.25.22), connection timed out
Err:3 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Reading package lists... Done                                     
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.201.250.36), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.229.132.181), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.229.150.131), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (34.237.137.22), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.73.36.184), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.91.65.63), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (52.207.133.243), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.152.129.43), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.165.17.230), connection timed out Could not connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (54.172.25.22), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.26), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: What command did you run? apt?

Comment: @DennisLi Yes, I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt update`, not sure which is right

Comment: @Garrett Have you verified if security groups has proper ports open for this EC2 instance?

Comment: It's the same.  you can check if the ecs are able to connect to the internet first. try  ping

Comment: @DennisLi ping doesn't work `11 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss`

Comment: @Prabhakar Security group with ports 80 and 22 for both inbound and out bound are set. I've also tried adding 443 and nothing works

Comment: @Garrett did you have a public IP? check the AWS console.

Comment: @Garrett Can you open all traffic in outbound and try again?

Comment: @DennisLi Yes it has a public IP

Comment: @Prabhakar opening all traffic doesn't work. and when I connect to the server it has this error `Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings`

Comment: @Garrett Does your subnet has route to Internet gateway?

Comment: How are you obtaining these logs? Are you connecting via SSH? From the Internet?

Comment: try to telnet 34.201.250.36 on port 80 from instance and run a traceroute. If you're not able to do so, it'a network configuration problem, it could be security group, Network ACL or even if the subnet routing table doesn't have any way to connect to internet

Comment: @Shree You mean like connected to a route table which has a route to an internet gateway? It has that, and the internet gateway two routes, one with 0.0.0.0/0 as the destination and the other with ::/0 as the destination

Comment: @JamesDean telnet didn't work: `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out` I'm pretty sure I have everything setup correctly though. Security groups have ssh (that works) and http, route table has access to internet subnet looks fine, everything

Comment: It's fixed... it was the Network ACL. I didn't have anything allowing http traffic in and I figured that wouldn't be a problem since it was the default settings after setting up the instance. Also, I just started with AWS two days ago so I am very lost. Thanks everyone

Comment: @Garrett tip: Network ACL are stateless which means you need to create both inbound and outbound rules where as security group are stateful.

Comment: @JamesDean Thanks for the tip

Answer (score -1):

Please change outbound rules to allow for http and https requ

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).